# Is there a way of displaying CRD resources in Rancher UI?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rook-storage

I deployed a Rook EdgeFS cluster (stateful set) and created a NFS custom resource, but now I can't find it anywhere in Rancher. If I query the cluster using kubectl, is possible to see that the resource is there:

```
kubectl get nfs
```

Is there a way of make Rancher display these custom resources somewhere in the UI?

Comment: Hi Jackson, you will not see nfs directly there. How I did in our installation: deployed rook-edgefs with some customizations, configured storage class and then in UI interface(or I believe you can do the same in efscli) - configured tenant, bucket and service. This service created a pod with nfs server. After that when creating pods I specify previously configured storage class which points to the 'service' and it creates PVC which are visible from Rancher.

Comment: PS: Are you still using edgefs? We have some issues with it but looks like it is not very popular and its hard to find useful troubleshooting info about it... 8(

Comment: Yes. I'm still using it. But it is stand by for now.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. In your cluster overview in Rancher, on the left side menu, go to "More Resource", then in the submenu go to "API", and then in final submenu open "CustomResourceDefinitions".

[image: CRD in Rancher]